# Execution of Javascript not working on CodePen

Tags: javascript, codepen

I have been playing around with codepen.io and came across this particular issue for which I am not able to resolve.

My following pen does not work in codepen but works locally on my machine, I am not sure if I have to do something extra or enable a feature on codepen to make it work.

Any help most appreciated :)

**HTML**

```
<span>Background color:</span>
  <select id="background">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  </select>

  <span>Width:</span>
  <select id="width">
    <option value="100px">100px</option>
    <option value="200px">200px</option>
    <option value="300px">300px</option>
  </select>

  <span>height:</span>
  <select id="height">
    <option value="100px">100px</option>
    <option value="200px">200px</option>
    <option value="300px">300px</option>
  </select>

  <br/>
  <br/>

  <div id="content" style="background:red; width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
```

**JS**

```
  // array of virtual DOM objects

var arraySelect = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

var content = document.getElementById('content');

// function
function dropdownStyles() {

 // apply the value from the select options (when applied) has the style values for content.

  var style = this.id;
  var value = this.value;

  content.style[style] = value;
}

// create a loop to iterate each select option in document add an event listener to each.

for( var i = 0; i < arraySelect.lenght; i++ ){

  // with dropdownStyles() the function will get executed so that is why we don't add the brackets

arraySelect[i].addEventListener('change',dropdownStyles);

}
```

[Red box changer - codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjZzKv)

Comment: arraySelect.**length**

Comment: what a day, such an obvious thing when you look back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo:
it's length not lenght

```
for( var i = 0; i < arraySelect.lenght; i++ ){
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code.

```
var arraySelect = document.querySelectorAll('select');

var content = document.getElementById('content');
arraySelect.forEach(function(v){
    v.addEventListener('change',dropdownStyles);
}) 
function dropdownStyles() {   
  var style = this.id;
  var value = this.value;
  content.style[style] = value;
}
```

this code will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> i < arraySelect.lenght

There is  lenght ,not length.